# Can't detect my wireless card in a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 11s

Tags: wireless

I'm new to ubuntu and wanted to dive into the new OS to get a feel with Linux. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 11s and installed google chrome and updates to the system. When they were done installing, I couldn't access internet anymore. There's no wifi icon and no networks show within the settings. There's no additional drivers that need to be installed.

```
$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    soft blocked: yes
    hard blocked: no
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280 
# no results
```

Also I ran a wireless script [option 2 from here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082305&p=12350385#post12350385)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Feb 2015 19:55 EST -0500

Booted last: 13 Feb 2015 19:52 EST -0500

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b35e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03eb:8814 Atmel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1a03 Corsair
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ideapad_laptop         18216  0
sparse_keymap          13948  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    19177  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dragonfly3]] (600 root)
[ipv6] method=auto
[connection] id=dragonfly3 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=dragonfly3 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[802-1x] system-ca-certs=true
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TiggleBittyNP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TiggleBittyNP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TiggleBittyNP | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh] (755 root)
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8723au)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: rfkill list all. Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: @chili555 I just made a few edits and ran a wireless script from a post I found on this site.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a known issue which requires modding the kernel (which is why I gave up, way back when). That means there's probably a duplicate out there to point at...

Comment: This card needs firmware from package `linux-firmware`. Is it installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device `ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.` is driven by the driver 8723au. It is not natively present in Ubuntu 14.04 at least in the 3.13.0-xx kernel version. However, it has obviously been compiled and has been used here before because we see networks you have connected to: [/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dragonfly3] for example. As well, we see a udev rule:

```
USB device 0x:0x (rtl8723au)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?", ATTR{address}=="",ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan", NAME="wlan0"
```

If you compiled the driver from source, it is necessary to recompile when a later kernel version is installed, for example, when 3.13.0-44 is updated to xx-45. In a terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads/rtl8723au  <---or wherever the downloaded source file is located
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8723au
```

Repeat this sequence whenever a later kernel version is installed by Update Manager.

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the explanation! :) If you could explain what make clean and sudo modprobe mean, that would be awesome. Also, I was able to add a few more commands to get a wireless icon showing on the panel too.

Comment: Glad it's working! 'make clean' simply means sweep away all the little bits and pieces, primarily .o and .ko files, created in any previous compilations and so that you then start fresh and make new parts. 'modprobe' loads the driver into your currently running kernel. Have fun!